# Auto save on database without having submit button on the table using x editable inline mode

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, x-editable

I am currently working on a Ruby On Rails(student) project displaying table with X editable plug-in. On the documentation on [x editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) to save the edited cell back to database, it used a "submit" button, Is it possible to exclude submit button and used the [check button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mamNH.png) on the inline mode. Like if the user click "enter" on the keyboard it will be automatically saved to the database. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at [their documentation](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable), I think it will autosubmit if you just switch the button off by setting `showbuttons` to false?

```
showbuttons

Where to show buttons: left(true)|bottom|false  
Form without buttons is auto-submitted.
```